# Codeception radio button selection issues

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver, codeception

I'm struggling Codeception Webdriver / Selenium to select on of the radio buttons.

```
<div id="edit-nationality" class="lw-radios form-radios toggle-btn-grp cssonly">
<div class="form-item form-item-nationality form-type-radio radio">
    <input type="radio" id="edit-nationality-yes" name="nationality" value="Yes" class="form-radio">
    <label class="toggle-btn" for="edit-nationality-yes">Yes </label><span class="lw-error-message"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-item-nationality form-type-radio radio">
    <input type="radio" id="edit-nationality-no" name="nationality" value="No" class="form-radio">
    <label class="toggle-btn" for="edit-nationality-no">No </label><span class="lw-error-message"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Selecting "No" works fine

```
$I->selectOption('#edit-nationality-no', 'No');
```

however selecting "Yes" does not

```
$I->selectOption('#edit-nationality-yes', 'Yes');
```

Thanks,

Comment: name="nationality[]"

Comment: unfortunately name="nationality[]" didn't change it

Comment: What is your code for `selectOption()`?

Comment: Hi JeffC, The code is in the question, it's exactly as shown there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using either

```
$I->selectOption('input[name=nationality]', 'Yes');
```

or as a work-around clicking the element

```
$I->click('#edit-nationality-yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to select radio button.

> $I->checkOption( 'input[value="Yes"]' );

No need to pass the second arg. This works for me in my script.